# Do browsers save keyboardinput in input-tags if these are not part of a form but are being parsed by javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, security, browser

I'm creating a webpage that has some input html-tags (the types are "text" and "password").
These tags are not part of a form. Instead, they are being parsed by javascript and they generate some output visible on the webpage.

Everything works fine, but I would like to know:

- If browsers save the given input somewhere else then just in memory
- How long the the browser remembers this input

For security-reasons I want to make sure that the only place where this data resides is in the RAM of the computer that visits the site. (And for the smallest amount of time possible)

(I already used traffic-sniffing to check that the data isn't being sent back to the webserver, so that part of the security has been checked)

With "browsers" I mean the most popular ones. I assume these are: Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge, IE, Opera.

If I'm unlucky and browsers would indeed save this info on disk, then I'm also interested in all tricks that I can use in javascript to disable this behavior.

Comment: Browsers save nothing, HTTP is stateless. If you're asking wether or not a form is submitted when there is no form, then nope !

Comment: Do you mean the suggestions users get when they type something in a input field? If so, why is that a security risk? PS: user credentials like username and password are saved in the computers version of a password manager.

Comment: Also, why would you need a password, if it's never sent to the server? Sounds like you're overthinking this, if it works for everyone else, including banks, it probably works for you as well.

Comment: @adeneo: I know that it's not being submitted. That's why i mentioned the traffic-sniffing check.But obviously the entered data has to at least be in the RAM of the computer running the browser for at least microseconds. (How else can the scripts handle the data)

Comment: And why is that a problem, that's just the way it works, the client is generally trusted?

Comment: @adeneo: password-type is needed because the entered input should not be visible for anyone else looking at the screen. Maybe i should have mentioned that the only task the webpage has to do is delivering the javascript and the webpage, everything else is done by the browser

Comment: Generally, yes. But in this case it's mostly because the user will be using a computer from another user

Comment: @shilly: suggestions would certainly be a problem, but i already checked this on multiple browsers, this is luckely (for me) not the case. Probably because i don't use a submit-button and no data has been sent to the webserver.

Comment: Sounds like you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), using a password field only deters onlookers. Autofill is usually based on the elements names, so that can easily be avoided. In general the browser won't store what's typed in the fields anywhere by default, unless your code does it, so you should be safe, but if someone has access to the client, adding a keylogger or any number of techniques, would completely circumvent that, which is why you should always trust the client, and if the client isn't safe, that's their problem.

Comment: If both users have separate user accounts on the same system, general windows security settings should avoid one user being able to access anything from the other user. If both users will use the same account on the same machine, you can never avoid one user impersonating another. And it has nothing to do with the page not being inside a form. Password management is done by the operating system, not the browser, so there's no way afaik to block this with JS. You can add `autocomplete="false"` to your inputs, but this won't prevent the users from cracking the passwords file on the machine.

Comment: @adeneo: That's what i wanted to know. Thanks !

Comment: @shilly: I don't use the password-inputtype to login somewhere, I use it as a way to send a variable to the javascript in such a way that nobody can see what this variable was.

Comment: Sidenote: A submit button inside a proper form just automatically creates an ajax request, parses all inputs using  FormData object and then POSTs it to the form action. Doing this manually with javascript is exactly the same, you just have more control over what gets sent and how.

Comment: @garo I don't understand this use case. Just using autocomplete false should do the trick, since you just use the input element to pass data. So you do not have a problem I think, unless you coded your inputs to use autocomplete. Alternatives are using a editable `<div>` or a 90's style `window.prompt()`. They don't get suggestions or saves or anything that are standard for input elements. So yes, this is a classic X/Y problem. :)